# Optimization with Python(spicy.optimize)-Constraints issue

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a mathematical problem using the code provided below. The code runs with no errors, but it prints a result without taking the constraints into consideration. p1 and p2 are the products of a plant and m1, m2, m3 are the raw materials needed for the production(I am providing this piece of information in case someone wonders what the equations between m1, m2 ,m3 and p1, p2 stand for). Any idea what might be wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

earnings_p1 = 150
earnings_p2 = 175
costs_m1 = 10
costs_m2 = 17
costs_m3 = 25

def objective(x):
    quantity_p1 = x[0]
    quantity_p2 = x[1]
    quantity_m1 = 2 * quantity_p1 + 1 * quantity_p2
    quantity_m2 = 5 * quantity_p1 + 3 * quantity_p2
    quantity_m3 = 0 * quantity_p1 + 4 * quantity_p2
    total_costs = quantity_m1 * costs_m1 + quantity_m2 * costs_m2 + quantity_m3 * costs_m3
    total_earnings = quantity_p1 * earnings_p1 + quantity_p2 * earnings_p2
    total_profit = total_earnings - total_costs
    return -total_profit

def constraint1(x):
    quantity_p1 = x[0]
    quantity_p2 = x[1]
    quantity_m1 = 2 * quantity_p1 + 1 * quantity_p2
    return 100 - quantity_m1

def constraint2(x):
    quantity_p1 = x[0]
    quantity_p2 = x[1]
    quantity_m2 = 5 * quantity_p1 + 3 * quantity_p2
    return 80 - quantity_m2

def constraint3(x):
    quantity_p1 = x[0]
    quantity_p2 = x[1]
    quantity_m3 = 0 * quantity_p1 + 4 * quantity_p2
    return 150 - quantity_m3

cons1 = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1})
cons2 = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2})
cons3 = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3})
cons = [cons1, cons2, cons3]

quantity_p1_guess = 10
quantity_p2_guess = 20

x0 = np.array([quantity_p1_guess, quantity_p2_guess])

solution = minimize(objective, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, options={'disp': True})
print(solution)
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? The constraints are not invalidated for me, but obviously the results do not look like something to target (sol of order - 10^9). Did you forget some variable bounds? And more relevant: are you trying to solve an Linear-Program using minimize? Don't do it (even if it feels simple). scipy.optimize.linprog is the way to go there.

Comment: @sascha yes I was trying to solve it with minimize.. I read in several blogs that it is possible to maximize an objective only by using a minus(as there is no option for maximize). Also, I am not sure how to use the variable bounds and the sol of order...Thank you for your help!

Comment: minimize is pretty general and not recommended for LPs. Bounds are documented. It's as easy as ```bounds=[(0,None),(0,None)]``` in your case. But that's a model-decision. ```sol of order -10^9```, which i described, just means: the original objective after minimization is ```~-308314878``` which is usually considered bad in terms of numerical-math (badly scaled) or a sign for a wrong model. (the max/min relation you described is correct)

Comment: @sascha much appreciated!